# No endpoint mapping found for..., using SpringWS, JaxB Marshaller

Tags: java, jaxb, spring-ws

I get this error: No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://mycompany/coolservice/specs}ChangePerson]

Following is my ws config file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
    <description>An endpoint mapping strategy that looks for @Endpoint and @PayloadRoot annotations.</description>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <description>Enables the MessageDispatchServlet to invoke methods requiring OXM marshalling.</description>
    <constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
</bean>

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPaths"> 
    <list>
        <value>org.company.xml.persons</value>
        <value>org.company.xml.person_allextensions</value>
        <value>generated</value>
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="persons" class="com.easy95.springws.wsdl.wsdl11.MultiPrefixWSDL11Definition">   
    <property name="schemaCollection" ref="schemaCollection"/>                                               
    <property name="portTypeName" value="persons"/>                                
    <property name="locationUri" value="/ws/personnelService/"/>                              
    <property name="targetNamespace" value="http://mycompany/coolservice/specs/definitions"/>       
</bean>

<bean id="schemaCollection" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">                   
    <property name="xsds">
    <list>
        <value>/DataContract/Person-AllExtensions.xsd</value>
        <value>/DataContract/Person.xsd</value>
    </list>
    </property>
     <property name="inline" value="true"/>      
</bean>
```

I have then the following files:

```
public interface MarshallingPersonService {

public final static String NAMESPACE = "http://mycompany/coolservice/specs";
public final static String CHANGE_PERSON = "ChangePerson";

public RespondPersonType changePerson(ChangePersonType request);
}
```

and

```
  @Endpoint
  public class PersonEndPoint implements MarshallingPersonService {

    @PayloadRoot(localPart=CHANGE_PERSON, namespace=NAMESPACE)
    public RespondPersonType changePerson(ChangePersonType request) {
        System.out.println("Received a request, is request null? " + (request == null ? "yes" : "no"));
        return null;        
    }

}
```

I am pretty much new to WebServices, and not very comfortable with annotations. I am following a tutorial on setting up jaxb marshaller in springws. I would rather use xml mappings than annotations, although for now I am getting the error message.

EDIT: ChangePersonType

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ChangePersonType", propOrder = {
"applicationArea",
"dataArea"
})
public class ChangePersonType {

@XmlElement(name = "ApplicationArea", namespace = "http://mycompany/coolservice/specs", required = true)
protected TransApplicationAreaType applicationArea;
@XmlElement(name = "DataArea", namespace = "http://mycompany/coolservice/specs", required = true)
protected DataArea dataArea;
@XmlAttribute(required = true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
protected String releaseID;
@XmlAttribute
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
protected String versionID;
```

--The rest are getters and setters.

Comment: I have also shot in the dark and set the NAMESPACE constant to "{http://mycompany/coolservice/specs}ChangePerson", but didnt work.

any idea/ suggestions how these annotations work to pick the ChangePerson up, and what I am doing wrong...?

Comment: Can you add the source for `ChangePersonType` also, or at least the first few lines of it.

Comment: done, it is generated by jaxb xjc compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. The parameter of the end point class and return variable had to be wrapped in JAXBElement, like JAXBElement. 
The reason is

> The classes generated by JAXB2 from
>   your schema come in two flavors: those
>   that have a @XmlRootElement
>   annotation, which can be used directly
>   as either parameter or response, and
>   those who haven't. Those classes which
>   haven't got this annotation need to be
>   wrapped in a JAXBElement.
>
> Besides the generated classes from
>   your schema, JAXB2 also generates an
>   ObjectFactory class, which clarifies
>   the use of JAXBElement. There are some
>   factory methods is there, which
>   illustrate how you can use the various
>   schema types.
>
> Arjen Poutsma
>   h ttp://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=49817

Comment: Note that I needed to specify <xjc:simple /> in my jaxb:globalBindings config to get the classes generated with @XmlRootElement